# How to read a csv file with muplitiple delimiter in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with delimiter (dot and underscore) and I am using sep='_.' in read_csv but it is not taking dot as sep while reading.

input
jks_12034.45_89.12

output
jks  12034  45  89  12

Comment: The point "." is a special character in regex, try to escape it with "\."

Comment: I have used sep="_\." but still not working

Comment: like this ... *sep = "_|\."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `engine='python'` and `sep=r'[_.]'` as parameters of `pd.read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=r'[_.]', engine='python', header=None)
print(df)

# Output
     0      1   2   3   4
0  jks  12034  45  89  12
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

> separators longer than 1 character and different from '\s+' will be interpreted as regular expressions

If you use `sep="_\."` it will only match a point where youhave both an underscore **AND** a dot.

If you want to split on unserscore **OR** dot use `sep="\.|_"` or `sep="[_\.]"`